# How to pause execution of setTimeout call without breaking up functions?

Tags: javascript

So I have an image that I want to fade out, replace, and then fade in. I didn't want to bother with jQuery for such a little task so I found a js fade in and fade out function and modified it to my liking.

At first my code was simple:

```
setTimeout(function(){fadeOut(id, val);},300);
set_slide(s1, current);
setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(id, val);},300);
```

I quickly learned this doesn't work because the `set_slide(args)` and the other `setTimeout(args)` will be called immediately, not blocked until the first `setTimeout(args)` is done running.

This has forced me to do something pretty ugly and chain my code together so that the second 2 function calls, `set_slide(args) and setTimeout(args)`, are called within `fadeOut` and my first setTimout became

```
setTimeout(function(){
        fadeOut(s1,slide_1,current,9);
},300);
```

full script:

```
var previous = 0; //will hold index of image directly before the current image
                        var current = 1; //will hold the index of the current image
                        var next = 2; //will hold the index of the image directly after the current image
                        var images = [];

                        var s1 = document.getElementById('slide1');
                        var s2 = document.getElementById('slide2');
                        var s3 = document.getElementById('slide3');


            var slide_1 = document.getElementById('slide1-img');
                    var slide_2 = document.getElementById('slide2-img');
                    var slide_3 = document.getElementById('slide3-img');

                    s2.addEventListener("click", moveBackward);//enable move forward image button
                    s3.addEventListener("click", moveForward);//enable move backwards image button


                    <?php 
                        //output each image src into an array
                        $photoCount=count($aboutGallery);
                        foreach ($aboutGallery as $photo){
                            echo 'images.push("'.$photo['full_url'].'");';
                        }
                    ?>
                    var lengthImg = images.length;

                    function moveForward(){
                        //each of these calls increases the index reference by 1 while looping
                        //around when the end of the array is reached
                        previous = (current)%(lengthImg); 
                        current = (current+1)%(lengthImg);
                        next = (current+1)%(lengthImg);

                        //set current slide
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            fadeOut(s1,slide_1,current,9);
                        },300);


                        //set previous and next slides
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            fadeOut(s2,slide_2,previous,9);
                            fadeOut(s3,slide_3,next,9);
                        },300);
                    }

function setSlide(container, slideNum){
                            container.src = images[slideNum];

                            if(document.readyState === 'complete'){//ensures scripts.js has been loaded and doesn't run on first load
                                setBackgroundImage();
                            }
                        }



function fadeOut(id,slide,position,val){
                              if(isNaN(val)){ val = 9;}
                              id.style.opacity='0.'+val;
                              //For IE
                             id.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';
                              if(val>0){
                                val--;
                                  console.log(position);
                                setTimeout(function(){fadeOut(id,slide,position,val)},50);
                              }else{
                                  //input next slide and fade in
                                  setSlide(slide, position);
                                  fadeIn(id,9);
                                  return;}

                            }
```

Comment: Is it working after your "ugly" chaining?

Comment: yes it works, but is there a way to pause the execution of scripts

Comment: There is no such thing as pausing in js, because the language is single threaded. You can cancel a setTimeout however. For that you need to store a reference `var timerReference = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);` and you can cancel the timeout at anytime by calling `clearTimeout(timerReference);`

Comment: If you consider this ugly you probably want to build some util like this one here: https://github.com/es128/async-waterfall . But basically this is how JS works

Comment: Use callbacks instead of statically always calling the same next function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solves the problem, but any code after the `test()` call will not wait, unless you use `.then()`

```
const timer = ms => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function test(){
      console.log('Starting')
      await timer(1000)
      console.log('after 1s')    

      await timer(2000)
      console.log('after 2s')

      await timer(3000)
      console.log('after 3s')
      console.log('Ended')
}

test()
```

In the most cases i use an IIFE.
Also i think async functions are well supported :
http://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions

http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises